# Ghost Docker Containers

Tags: docker

While doing a `docker ps` to find out if I had running docker container before I boot up my project, I saw something really strange. I had  running container that I didn't asked for. Since it was an anonymous container, I wanted to find out more info about it. If I do a `docker ps -a` there's a bunch of it, I'm really concerned... maybe someone can give me an hint ?

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
ccbeb0fb879a   065366ccb1b4                             "composer update --d…"   7 days ago     Created                               boring_antonelli
1da76cd9c835   065366ccb1b4                             "composer update --d…"   8 days ago     Created                               jovial_mestorf
ca4e8785df51   122045e9b2a4                             "composer update --d…"   8 days ago     Created                               friendly_dewdney
ef8e3a48c617   122045e9b2a4                             "composer update --d…"   8 days ago     Created                               angry_galileo
d91012776cef   122045e9b2a4                             "composer update --d…"   8 days ago     Created                               peaceful_ramanujan
b8bdf58a9b26   122045e9b2a4                             "composer update --d…"   9 days ago     Created                               magical_napier
d9be3f6111a2   9d116052c99d                             "composer update --d…"   10 days ago    Created                               sweet_chatterjee
0f582c3f5e76   9d116052c99d                             "composer update --d…"   11 days ago    Created                               funny_leavitt
```

Comment: `docker inspect` them

Comment: Thanks ! Found where they belongs. Still don't understand why they spawned tho.

Comment: It's not the question however it's good to know that you can stop and remove all containers with this one-liner `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`